# Java convert hex to time

Tags: java, time, hex

I really have no idea where to start on this, I have done some research but been unable to find anything. I know I have to use the date class but what i need to do is pull out the date as highlighted below but the hex value is AA where is it getting the date value from?

image is here as it wont let me upload an image: http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?pid=2298915&l=e45630aead&id=1283154964

If any one knows I would be most greatful!

Many thanks

Comment: are you having trouble pulling the hex value, or trouble converting that hex to a date? I'm not sure I'll be able to help you but some more detail may help others to understand and help you.

Comment: Do you know exactly what hex value is to be converted? Btw., this is hardly a Java question, you need to understand the underlying format, the read the bytes (*no hex involved!*), convert them to a number (giving e.g. seconds since the Epoch or however the format is defined) and then convert the number to a time.

Answer (score 0):

Windows stores FileTime internally as the number of 100-nanoseconds since 1.1.1601 UTC as a 64bit field.

Is it possible for you to use JNI and call Windows API's FileTimeToSystemTime()? If so have a look here:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724280(VS.85).aspx

If not:

Do you know where this 64bit field is located in the datastructure you have there? You pointed out the address 03A0B00A (the 'AA' byte), however i find it unlikely that the field would be located there instead of maybe 03A0B008 or even 03A0B000 or 03A0B0C0. If you dont know the address of this field you might reverse-engineer it by calculating the date (29.1.2011) in the 100-nanosecond-format; it need not be precise, you just have to find the most significant bytes and thus you know where the 64bit field lies. I dont know if Java lets you calculate in nanoseconds relative to 1.1.1601 UTC, however as i said it need not be precise: you can use Java to calculate the days since 1.1.1601 UTC, and then multiply accordingly; you can again use this estimate to find the address of the 64bit field and from then on use that address to calculate the time.

Answer (score 0):

The bytes in the file are: AA37 D608 DFBF CB01.

You can see in the left hand column that this is interpreted as the 64-bit integer 129407978957060010. If you convert that back to hex you will see that the number is stored in "little-endian" format: 01CB BFDF 08D6 37AA.

So what you need to do is:

```
    byte[] data = new byte[] { (byte) 0xAA, (byte) 0x37, (byte) 0xD6,
            (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0xDF, (byte) 0xBF, (byte) 0xCB, (byte) 0x01 };

    // convert bytes to long time
    long val = 0;
    for(int i=7;i>=0;i--) {
        val <<= 8;
        val += 0xff & data[i];
    }

    // convert 100 nanos to milliseconds
    val /= 10000;

    // convert to time offset from 1st Jan 1601 AD
    Calendar calend = Calendar.getInstance();
    calend.set(1601,0,01,00,00,00);
    calend.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    val += calend.getTimeInMillis();
    calend.setTimeInMillis(val);

    // display result
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
    System.out.println(df.format(calend.getTime()));
```